# How to use an object not declared in the UI file as signal receiver with QUiLoader?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5, qt-designer

I want to use multiple UI files for different components of my main window as well as the main window itself (because I for example want an extra UI file for the menubar and the toolbar, because both might get quite big), but make `<connections>` between signals of the widgets in the UI files and slots of the mainwindow. I have right now:

#### mainwindow.ui

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
    <class>mainwindow</class>
    <widget class="FGaugeMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
        <property name="title">
            <string>FGauge</string>
        </property>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="MainWidget">
        </widget>
        <widget class="QStatusBar" name="StatusBar">
        </widget>
    </widget>
</ui>
```

#### menubar.ui

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
    <class>menubar</class>
    <widget class="FGaugeMenuBar" name="MenuBar">
        <widget class="QMenu" name="MenuFile">
            <property name="title">
                <string>File</string>
            </property>
            <addaction name="ActionFileOpen"/>
        </widget>
        <action name="ActionFileOpen">
            <property name="text">
                <string>Open …</string>
            </property>
        </action>
        <addaction name="MenuFile"/>
    </widget>
    <connections>
        <connection>
            <sender>ActionFileOpen</sender>
            <signal>triggered()</signal>
            <receiver>MainWindow</receiver>
            <slot>loadProject()</slot>
        </connection>
    </connections>
</ui>
```

The `menubar.ui` is loaded by a custom subclass of `QUiLoader` (for the custom `FGaugeMainWindow` and `FGaugeMenuBar` subclasses) then set as menubar for the main window with `setMenuBar()`. But the connections of course don't work since when `QUiLoader` loads `menubar.ui` containing the connections, it doesn't know anything about the main window defined in `mainwindow.ui` and its slots.

How can this be done, if at all ? Of course I could just move the menu bar UI into the mainwindow UI file, but as I add more menus and menu items and widgets, the file would get quite big ... which I would want to avoid if somehow possible.

I'm using Qt 5.15.3 with C++.

Comment: Why are you concerned about the size of each ui file?

Comment: @ekhumoro Because I find it very tiresome to work with files with 1000 lines ! ;)

Comment: In what way are you "working" with them? The files would normally be auto-generated if you're using the Qt tools. Are editing them by hand or something?

Comment: @ekhumoro I use Qt Designer only for the initial setup of the widgets - further edits (such as adding another menu item) I do by hand.

Comment: I can't imagine any advantage of partial editing by hand. It seems like the worst possible option. You might as well do everything in code if you're that averse to using the Qt Designer interface. Choosing to program in xml is really making a rod for your own back.

Comment: I actually find it very easy to work with (since I'm alreadyused to programmign in XML) as long as the file isn't too big ! ;)

Comment: In your question, you don't actually explain why you can't use the Qt Designer interface to create the menus and toolbars within the main-window. Doing things that way avoids all the problems with signal connections, and the file size becomes irrelevant since there's no need to manually edit it. This would seem to provide a valid answer to the specific question: "how can this be done, if at all"? Apart from that, your question looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), since you never really explain what the underlying issue is (assuming there actually is one).

Comment: @ekhumoro Even if I had only one file containing the top-level mainwindow (which would fix the signal connection problem), I want to make some signals call slots of my `QAppliaction` subclass, that are also used from the CLI of my application. What I basically want is a possibility to make QUiLoader use a custom class instead of the default FormBuilder instance to map connections.

Comment: That seems to be something that should be done in code. Why do you need to do it via the ui file?

Comment: @ekhumoro Because then the UI is independent from the code, and also the C++ code for 100 menu items would get veryyyyyyy long …

Comment: You said: "I want to make ***some*** signals call slots of my QApplication subclass, that are also used from the CLI of my application". How is that "100 menu items"? Also, the `QApplication` and CLI clearly aren't part of the GUI, so the ui-loader shouldn't be dependent on them. And why do you think you need a custom class to map connections? Please edit your question and explain *in detail* exactly what it is you are trying to achieve (i.e. concentrate on the X instead of continuing to focus on the Y).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is not possible (I deduce that from looking at the source code) to reference a signal of a widget not defined in the UI file the connection is defined in (without ducplicating `QUiLoader` in its entirety), I decided to use a custom format for the menubar - will be less verbose anyways.